# Strange behavior if statement in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I'm facing a very strange problem, it's supposed to be a very easy problem but I'm running around in circles since 2 days.
I am setting up a login form, there are 3 types of users: Admin, Employee and user.
I created a simple "if else" statement. In the first "if" I check if the user is an admin then I display the page, in the second if it is an employee and in the third if it is a user.
It works without problem for the first two "if" (admin and employee) but not for the user.

```
private void connexion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        employee.setLogin(request.getParameter("login"));
        employee.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        user.setLogin(request.getParameter("login"));
        user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
       
         
        User user1 = new User();
        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        
        user1 = user.findUser(request.getParameter("login"), request.getParameter("password"));
        employee1 = employee.findEmployee(request.getParameter("login"), request.getParameter("password"));
        
            
         if (employee1 != null && "Employee".equals(employee1.getStatus().getStatus()))
         {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("employee", employee1);
          this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/employee.jsp").forward(request, response);-->Ok
        }
         else if(employee1 != null && "Admin".equals(employee1.getStatus().getStatus())) 
         {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("employee", employee1);
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
         else if (user1 != null && "User".equals(user1.getStatus().getStatus())) 
         {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user1);
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/user.jsp").forward(request, response);--> Not working here.
        }
        
         
    }
```

But if I put the user in the first place, it works for the user but not for the other two. really strange, I hope you understood lol

```
    if (user1 != null && "User".equals(user1.getStatus().getStatus())) 
    {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user1);
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/succ.jsp").forward(request, response);--> Now it's working
   }
    
    else if (employee1 != null && "Employee".equals(employee1.getStatus().getStatus()))
     {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("employee", employee1);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/employee.jsp").forward(request, response);-->doesn't work
    }
     else if(employee1 != null && "Admin".equals(employee1.getStatus().getStatus())) 
     {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("employee", employee1);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);-->Doesn't work
    }
```

Here is the error message I got

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "model.Status.getStatus()" because the return value of "model.Employee.getStatus()" is null
```

I debbuged and it's not true, getStatus is not null...

The jsp is a simple form

```
<form method="post" action="connexion"> 
                        <h2>Connexion</h2>
                                    
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label>Login </label>
                        <input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                        <span class="erreur">${form.errors['firstName']}</span>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <label>password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="required"/>
                        <span class="erreur">${form.errors['lastName']}</span>
                    </fieldset>                                     
                    
                    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Ouvrir session" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>

                    
                </form>
```

findEmployee and findUser :

```
@Override
    public Employee findEmployee(String login, String password) {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;    
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Status status = new Status();

        
        try {
            connection = MysqlDaoFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LOGIN);
            ps.setString(1, login );
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()) {
                employee.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                employee.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
                employee.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
                employee.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                employee.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                employee.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
                employee.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                employee.setActive(rs.getBoolean("active"));
                employee.setStatus(status.findbyId(rs.getInt("statusId")));


            }
        }catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
             MysqlConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection);
                MysqlConnectionFactory.closeResultSet(rs);
            }
            return employee;
        }

@Override
    public User findUser(String login, String password)
    {
        
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        User user = new User();
        Status status = new Status();
        Country country = new Country();

        try {
            connection = MysqlDaoFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_LOGIN);
            ps.setString(1, login);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()) {
                user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                user.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
                user.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
                user.setBirthDate(rs.getDate("birthDate"));
                user.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                user.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
                user.setZipCode(rs.getString("zipCode"));
                user.setCity(rs.getString("city"));
                user.setPhone(rs.getString("phone"));
                user.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
                user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                user.setActive(rs.getBoolean("active"));
                user.setSolde(rs.getDouble("solde"));
                user.setCountry(country.findById(rs.getInt("countryId")));
                user.setStatus(status.findbyId(rs.getInt("statusId")));
        
            }
            
        }catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        finally
        {
            MysqlConnectionFactory.closePreparedStatement(ps);
            MysqlConnectionFactory.closeResultSet(rs);
            MysqlConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection); 
        }
            
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to use a debugger and see what's actually happening.

Comment: Hi Thomas, when I debug I see that the status is not empty it shows the right status

Comment: What does `Status.getStatus()` do? Why do you need to call `getStatus().getStatus()` anyway? And what does `status.findbyId(rs.getInt("statusId"))` actually do or return? This looks as if `Status` is some kind of repository - is that intended? Could debugging and thus stalling execution cause side effects in that `Status` gets more time to "initialize"?

Comment: Your code looks as if it could be sharing the `Status` entity (it it one?) between users and employees (you're loading both upfront) if they have the same `statusId`. Could that cause an unintended side effect? Also, why do you load users and employee at the same time? I'd try with one first and load the other only if the first fails. And why is there a distinction between the 2 classes, i.e. aren't employees just users with a special status?

Comment: I have 3 differents tables in my database, User, employee and status, I just stored the all the status in the table, so getStatus.getStatus() return "Admin","Employee" or "User". And the method findById return the right status of the user.

Comment: Well, it looks like it doesn't always return the status (maybe one of your entities has a wrong mapping) or the status is being changed in between. From the code you've posted it's hard to spot an error (if there even is one in that part) and that's why you need to debug thoroughly and look for unintended side effects.

Comment: Another question though: you always put those "-->Ok", "-->Doesn't work" etc. on the calls to the dispatcher. Does that mean you expect a dispatch to multiple jsps?

Comment: Yes Status is an entity. User and employees cannot have the same statusId because. I loaded in the same time because it's same form maybe i can create another form if it's possible with the same one. I couldn't created just one class because the employes  can do many more actions than users

Comment: I will debug again to try to find the flaw, and concerning the dispatch it was just to see if it works but I will redirect to the same page but the content of the page will be different depending on the status

Comment: I understood that it doesn't go beyond the first if I don't know why

Comment: It looks like it could happen when there are same login and password for an Admin/Employee and a User. ex) User(login:aaa, password:111), Admin(login:aaa, password:111)

Comment: And `employee1 != null`, `user1 != null` conditions are completely useless according to your code.

Comment: And you are using same `SQL_LOGIN` to find user and employee according to your code.

Comment: "it doesn't go beyond the first if" - well, if there is a user with the given data then why should it? If there is no such user or the user's status is not "User" only then should the else branch be executed (note that there is no actual "else if" construct - it's more like another if inside the else branch)

Comment: @Jejun I tried by removing employee1 != null and user1 != null, same result and SQL_LOGIN is not same I have two different classes EmployeeDaoImpl where the SQL_LOGIN is SELECT * FROM employe where login =? AND password=?" and the other class UserDaoImpl where the SQL_LOGIN is SELECT * FROM user where login =? AND password=?"

Comment: @Thomas if I enter the user's credentials  e.g: login = user password = user and status = user, it enters the first condition (employee1 != null && "Employee".equals(employee1.getStatus().getStatus()))"
It sees that the status = null and it stops, it does not enter the last condition

Comment: "I tried by removing employee1 != null and user1 != null, same result" - that's what "completely useless" means. Those reference are never null according to your code so whether you have them or not doesn't change a thing. "It sees that the status = null and it stops, it does not enter the last condition" - that's expected if you get a NullPointerException at `employee1.getStatus().getStatus()` since execution of `connexion()` ends by throwing this exception to the caller. So you need to figure out why you get that NPE and why your debugging doesn't result in one (if that's really the case).

Comment: I really tried everything, I debugged and I just saw anything except that it doesn't go beyond the first condition because Status is null , I will to completely change my method because I'm starting to go crazy